# How to get location services to keep prompting if users says "no"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CLLocation ask again for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245299/cllocation-ask-again-for-permission)
>   [How to prompt user to turn on Location Services…again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998465/how-to-prompt-user-to-turn-on-location-services-again)

I would like to have the "use your current location" alert to keep prompting if the user says "no".

Currently in the app I'm working on, if the user says "no" the prompt never shows again. I'm wondering how to keep the prompt/alert alive if they return to the view controller.

thanks for any help

Comment: Wouldn't that be incredibly frustrating for the user?

Comment: sure, the only problem is that after it asks once, it never asks again and the table data results aren't returned. so, if they touch "no" by mistake the app is useless :D

Comment: I think this is better rephrased into something like "How to get location services to reprompt the user for location permission if they accidentally refused it"

Comment: yeah, that's a better rephrasal. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is designed to ask only once (and for good reason). You can check if location services are enabled for your app and pop a message like "Please enable location services...".

Edit: you can check if location services are enabled with

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
```

Comment: ok, so just leave it as is then. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Corelocationmanager will fire `- (void)locationManager:didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` whenever you try to call methods like `startUpdatingLocation`. So you can check whether user has denied Location monitoring using the following code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
      if([error code] == kCLErrorDenied){
        //Alert view
      }
}
```

You can enable the Corelocation alert again by resetting location warnings. Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings. Also you can add alertview asking the user to direct to Settings Application and reset location warning there. Use following code inside Alert view delegate to open Settings Application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```